# Changing Android PopupMenu text color is not working

Tags: android, css

Another android theme style question... since I searched the site and can't find the answer here is my question.

I'm trying to change the text color of the PopupMenu shown by the action bar overflow, but It is not changing. It changes that background just fine, but not the text color. Btw this is code generated by "Android Action Bar Style Generator", I just added the Text appearance tag.

Here is my code:

```
<style name="Theme.Styles_mr_action_bar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_styles_mr_action_bar</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Styles_mr_action_bar</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Styles_mr_action_bar</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenu.TextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/PopupMenu.TextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>


<style name="PopupMenu.Styles_mr_action_bar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_styles_mr_action_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.TextAppearanceSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.TextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Any clue what is happening? I'm testing it in android 4.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys so I spent almost a week trying to change this but there was no way to do it... So what did I do? just created a popup and attached it to an action item that looked like a overflow menu.

```
PopupMenu mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.fake_overflow_item));
mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_popup_menu, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
mPopupMenu.show();
```

something really important about the anchor view of a PopupMenu is that you have to get it directly from your activity with findViewById(). If you get it from MenuItemCompat.getActionView(), the PopupMenu will raise an exception. I make this clear because I had problems with this and nowhere is stated that you have to get it from there.

I hope this helps someone!